# How to align bottom edges of mdframes with bottom of text area

Tags: vertical-alignment, mdframed

I've got a problem with the alignment of the bottom edges of "mdframes". These aren't aligned with the bottom of the text area, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.92}

\newmdenv[%
  backgroundcolor=lightgray,
  skipabove=\medskipamount,
  skipbelow=\medskipamount,
  splittopskip=\topskip,
  splitbottomskip=6pt,
  linewidth=1pt]%
  {grayBox}

\begin{document}

\begin{grayBox}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{itemize}
  \item a
  \item b
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{grayBox}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{grayBox}
\lipsum[6]
\end{grayBox}

\lipsum[1-6]


\end{document}
```

The bottom edges on pages 1 and 2 are not aligned:

[image: bottom edges on pages 1 and 2]

Moreover, the bottom edge of the last box on page 3 is not aligned with the bottom of the text area on page 4:

[image: bottom edges on pages 3 and 4]

How can I achieve that in both cases the bottom edges of the "mdframes" are aligned with the bottom edge of the text area?

Comment: I don't think you can. Even without the frames, the bottoms of pages don't always align. This misalignment will happen anytime something is added whose vertical height that is not an integer multiple of `\baselineskip`. E.g., slight changes to the itemize environment put the bottom of the pages out of line. The gray boxes add a little space for the starting and ending lines, so that is a possible source of misalignment. Anyway, I think you don't want the box edges to align with text, you want *text* to align with *text*. You might try changing the dimensions on page 6 of the mdframed doc.